# Sharepoint Online - Filter calculated column

Tags: sharepoint, filter, calculated-columns

I have created a calculated column that returns 0 or 1 based on another column. I would like to filter my items so it just shows me the entries with a "1" on this calculated column.
The list is capable of showing the filter 0 or 1 but when I click on it, it doesn't return any value.
[See image here for filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bp4NG.png).
[Results when filtering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtK3Q.png)

Anyone has any idea of what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Pictures are useful to aid the explanation, but we can't fix pictures, we need code for that. It would be like trying to fix a car by just looking at the smoke coming from the engine, and not the engine itself.

Comment: Apologies. The formula is:     =IF([Employee ID]=Round,1,0). The column is a Calculated column and I set up the data type to be return as 'Number'